# Missing separator error in Makefile after calling a custom function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm writing a macro that creates an empty target file name from a given name. And also redirects the named target to that empty target name.

After running this function I'm expecting my Makefile to look like this:

```
a:./build/._a

./build/._a:
        @echo building $@
```

However I constantly get this:

```
$ make a
a:./build/._a
Makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Here's my Makefile:

```
define empty_target
$(eval $2:=./build/._$1)
$(info $1:$($2))
$(eval $1:$($2))
endef

$(call empty_target,a,_A)

$(_A):
        @echo building $@
```

Comment: Define `empty_target` as two empty lines, and you get the error.  With that, replace the call by `$(empty_target)`, you get the error as well.  That's weird and looks like a bug or at least a misfeature of `gmake`.

Comment: @AProgrammer thanks for weighing in!

Comment: The expansion of `empty_target` is not empty, even though it's just white space (two newlines), hence the error. Not an error in my 4.2.1, but it is in 3.82. You could use `$(strip $(call empty_target,a,_A))`

Comment: @bobbogo Thanks very much for the explanation. Finally understand where the error comes from. I was using Make 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
define empty_target
$(eval $2:=./build/._$1)
$1:$($2)
endef

$(eval $(call empty_target,a,_A))

$(info _A=$(_A))

$(_A):
        @echo building $@
```

And yes, there's a nested eval, which you need if you want the variable assignment to take effect inside of the eval call (otherwise `$2` is expanded before it is set, and expands to blank).

As to your original code, I agree, it's somewhat confusing why it raises that error.   I can reproduce, and if I add the line `blah:blah2` in the middle of `empty_target`, it seems to get rid of the message.  I'm guessing it is a bug in how make colapses whitespace/newlines between the `$(eval)` calls.

Comment: This is still very good. Just tried it and worked nicely. Thanks a lot!